# How to use getopt in Linux?

Tags: linux

So I have a homework that wants me to build a script that mounts images and extracts the files to a certain path. Now, I am asked to give the script an optional parameter "--destination" which takes a new path to extract the files to. My teacher wants me to use getopt package so I installed it and tried to use it but I can't get it working and I can't find any examples on how to use getopt.
This is how I tried to read the new path

```
getopt -l destination:: -- "$@"
```

Now if I print the destination variable it would not print only the destination. How can I make it print only the destination?

Comment: See the example here: https://dustymabe.com/2013/05/17/easy-getopt-for-a-bash-script/

Comment: `getopt` doesn't set variables.

Comment: And is there any way to set a variable after doing that? I don't really understand that script Barmar posted. I am a very beginner in bash

Comment: did you look at the example? You assign the output of `getopt` to a variable then loop through that.

Comment: Linux needs a getopt package to be installed? Also, Linux is not Unix.